# How do I give a group access to see all projects in an organization without giving admin rights?

Tags: azure-devops

In our company developers are relatively free to join and work on projects as they please if they think they can contribute to them. We have recently migrated from TFS where devs could see all projects, but in  Azure DevOps all projects are hidden by default unless you are in the Project Collection Administrators group or invited to the project.

I want to allow devs to see all projects in our organization without having to be explicitly invited and without granting them outright Project Collection Administrator rights. I cannot find a permission to allow this under Organization Settings > Permissions however. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot find a permission to allow this under Organization Settings > Permissions however. Is this possible?

If you want to grant global read permissions for a group **without giving admin rights**, I am afraid it is impossible.

We have to set permissions for different projects separately. We could use an group and add it to the readers or contributors group for each team project.

That because when we are managing our project, we don't have people moving between projects that frequently - they're usually focused on one (or a few) at a time. Also, since we're doing work for clients, our projects tend to be relatively short-lived (order of months) and include outside users who can't be allowed to see the other projects.

In other words, if someone can access all of our source code, this makes it a pain to manage security and you want to create server level groups to manage this and his permissions are almost the same as administrator permissions. That the reason why `Project Collection Administrator` has permissions to access all the projects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would I be able to create a group that inherits from Project Collection Administrators and then deny the more dangerous permissions?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it is a pretty manual process to maintain.
You can:

1. create a new Group under Organization Settings > Permissions;
2. Add the members you need to it, on the "Members" tab;
3. Add each of the project's team under "Member of" tab, for instance, for read access you'd add [ProjectName]\Readers (repeat for every project);